# image report with different datasources

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report build from two different data sources. My tablix is linked to datasource1 and I need to show images based on the product name these images URL is present in datasource2. Any suggestions how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) function to join two datasets using a common field.

Add a column to your tablix and use this expression in `Fill` tab in `Text box` properties. Also select `External` for the image source.

[image]

In the `Use this image` property use this expression:

```
=Lookup(
  Fields!ProductNameDS1.Value,
  Fields!ProductNameDS2.Value,
  Fields!ProductImageURL.Value,
  "DataSet2"
)
```

**UPDATE:** Concatenate a hardcoded string to the beginning of every product URL.

```
="s7d1.scene8.com/is/image/product/" & Lookup(
  Fields!ProductNameDS1.Value,
  Fields!ProductNameDS2.Value,
  Fields!ProductImageURL.Value,
  "DataSet2"
)
```

**UPDATE 2:** Image is public in a web server.

```
="http://s7d1.scene8.com/is/image/product/" & Lookup(
  Fields!ProductNameDS1.Value,
  Fields!ProductNameDS2.Value,
  Fields!ProductImageURL.Value,
  "DataSet2"
)
```

`ProductNameDS1` is the product name in your first dataset and `ProductNameDS2` is the product name in the second dataset.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my issue is that the complete image url is not present in dataset2 i have to append some value how can i do that?

Comment: @sam, what is the value you need to append?

Comment: "http://s7d1.scene8.com/is/image/product/"

Comment: @sam, I've updated the expression, give it a try.

Comment: I did try it image is not being displayed getting a red cross in the place of image

Comment: @sam, Is the image public in a web server? Can you get the image via web browser? If so try the second update.

Comment: yes it is present in the server yes your second update works how can I adjust the size for those images

Comment: @sam, If you want to specify the size you have to use an Image item from the Toolbox window, drag and drop it to your textbox and use the same expression. In the Size tab you can specify the size. If my answer solved you issue you can mark it as the correct answer, [How to mark an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).